# WinPhone 8 Landscape splash screen

Tags: windows-phone-8, xamarin.forms, splash-screen

I'm creating a Xamarin.Forms app which will work in landscape mode.
I want the WinPhone8 splash screen in Landscape only.

However, the splash image is shown in Portrait at first, and then rotated to landscape when the `SupportedOrientations` is set.

How do I get the splash screen in landscape?

Answer (score 0):

I think landscape splash screens aren't supported on Windows Phone.

If it's a universal app you could try the method below, but I'm not sure if it only works on Windows Store apps.

Open up your app's manifest file and see if there is something like this in there;

```
   <InitialRotationPreference>
      <Rotation Preference="landscape"/>
      <Rotation Preference="landscapeFlipped"/>
   </InitialRotationPreference>
```

If not, add it :)
This tells your app to tell the OS that it wants to be in landscape initially.